# Orthographic View Alignment on the Y-Axis

Tags: objects, geometry, object-mode, origin, axis

If I create a cube, move it away in the x direction, and zoom all the way in toward it (i.e. from either left or right), its center is still aligned with the origin:

[image: x-axis alignment]

Same with the z direction. But if I move the cube in the y direction and zoom in toward it (i.e. from either front or back), its center creeps below the xy-plane:

[image: y-axis alignment]

[image: y-axis alignment]

I am new to Blender so I'm not sure if I'm somehow misunderstanding the orthographic view, but I could not think of a possible reason it should be behaving differently on the y-axis than it does on the other two. When I tried the same thing in Rhino 3d, for example, this did not happen. I am just wondering if this is an indication of some more general feature of orthographic view that I need to be aware of and account for.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm quite sure this is some floating point error...

Comment: @RobinBetts im interested to see the problem, i can't reproduce it on Blender 3.6

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie [Here it is](https://blend-exchange.com/b/R8R2j46D/) .. Take care not to move the view before seeing it.. the object origin should appear coincident with World 0, in an ortho view.

Comment: i can see it now! thanks for sharing but i cant reproduce it once i move around. but he probably can report it as a bug!

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie .. not sure you can call it a 'bug' .. more an inherent floating-point limitation, at extremes,  in the method chosen to create this view? The method may be sub-optimal, but correctly implemented. I guess you could still report it.. you would have to be diplomatic :D